# Selecting all elements that do not have an "id" attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, selector

How can I select all the elements on a page that do not have an "id" attribute? What is the selector for this in jQuery?

Comment: You mean the attribute _not set_ or not that attribute at all?

Comment: I mean the element will not have an "id" attribute at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `$(':not([id])')`. That should work fine.

Answer (score 11):

Negative selector `:not([id])` should work. See:

- http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/

Comment: Will $('*:not([id]') work for all elements? Or $(':not([id]')??

Comment: It does not matter. `*` is redundant if you want to select elements regardless of their tag name or class or whatever else besides `id` absence. If you would want to select `P` elements only, you would use `$('P:not([id])')`.

Comment: @Starx: It works, but `:not([id])` is also selecting for example `body`. The `div`s are inheriting `color` from `body`. If you change it to `div:not([id])`, your (flawed!) example works as you desire: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/HacpQ/4/

Comment: Another option is to just specify context (e.g. `BODY`): `$('BODY :not([id])')`.

Comment: @thirtydot, I know that, now why dont you tell Marat Tanalin to include that in his answer.

Comment: Answer exactly corresponds to the question: "How can i select *all* the elements on a page that does not have an "id" attribute?" BODY, HTML, HEAD, and other elements outside of BODY are included in *all* term.